# Improving the look of applications forwarded over X on a Mac

Tags: linux, mac, xforwarding

I use a Mac, but do all my development on a remote Linux machine which I access over SSH. Recently I've started using X forwarding to show some of the remote machine's graphical applications in windows on the Mac desktop. For the most part, this works really well - except that the applications look terrible: huge fonts, ugly widgets...

Being the Mac-using perfectionist I am, I want to try and improve the look of these windows. Is there any way of using alternative widgets in an X-forwarded application? What would I need to install on the Mac, or on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of development you do, would it make sense to use [NX (nomachine)](http://www.nomachine.com/)? for accessing these Linux boxes? Nomachine, or its free clones, allow you to access a Linux desktop much like one would access a Windows machine via RDP. I use it at work in a similar situation, and it handles quite well.